# QListWidget drag drop internalMove signal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I did change the `dragDropMode` of my `QListWidget` to `InternalMove`. Now it is possible to change the order of the items via drag and drop.

I now need to execute a function anytime the order of the items is changed.
Therefore, I would like to `connect` a signal to one of my functions.

However, I struggle to find the right signal.
I tried many (e.g.: `itemChanged`) but so far without luck.

Does somebody know which signal is emitted when I change the item order via drag and drop?

Example: I would like to connect a `drag_drop` action to the `self.drag_drop_happened()` function.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout
import sys
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Drag Drop enabled")
        vbox= QVBoxLayout()
        self.list = QListWidget()
        self.list.insertItem(0, "A")
        self.list.insertItem(1, "B")
        self.list.insertItem(2, "C")
        self.list.insertItem(3, "D")
        self.list.setDragDropMode(self.list.InternalMove)
        vbox.addWidget(self.list)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()
        # self.list connect to self.drag_drop_happened()
        
    def drag_drop_happened(self):
        pass
    
App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.list.model().rowsMoved.connect(self.drag_drop_happened)
```

> void QAbstractItemModel::rowsMoved(const QModelIndex &parent, int start, int end, const QModelIndex &destination, int row)